# Game Identification: Bidding/Bluffing game with royalty theme

Tags: identify-this-game

There is a board game I played with a group a few years ago that I can't seem to find.

Aspects of the board game I think I remember correctly (of course, memory is a fickle thing and these might still be incorrect):

1. The main playing grid was a 4x4 or 5x5 grid of characters
2. The characters were thematically themed as members of a royal court (such as a queen and a spymaster).
3. In each round, one of the characters was the "target" (unfortunately, I can't remember exactly what was special about them).
4. There are clue cards facedown that help identify who the "target" is, but each player knows a different combination of clues. (e.g. player 1 knows clues A & B, player 2 knows clues B & C, and player 3 knows clues C & A).
5. I think there is always the same number of clues regardless of player count, but am very unsure on that. I also do not remember how many clues there are.
6. During each round, players would take turns (more than one turn each round) betting with chips on spots on the grid on whether the target is present there (e.g. A bet beside the first row indicates the target is in the first row, a bet on a character indicates that character is the target, or a bet in between four characters indicates the target is one of those four).
7. The number of bets that can be placed in a specific spot is limited (e.g. only one or two bets can be on the first row, but I don't remember what the limit is).
8. Since players are taking turns placing bets, players would try to use their bets to trick other players into betting in the wrong spot.

I would be very grateful of any help identifying this game, thanks.

Comment: Was it an English game, or possibly in a different language?  There's apparently some Russian Da Vinci Code game (Kod DaVinci, po sledam velikih tayn) which has a hierarchy of monks (royal court?), secret artifacts (one character is the target), and some sort of bluffing mechanics.

Comment: It was definitely English. If it is originally in another language, the version we played was an official translation.